# mutation rate for permutation encoding

Tags: mutation

in scheduling n jobs on m machines problem
chromosome encoding is permutation encoding, each gene is a job number.
each chromosome has n genes
in mutation, I just swap 2 random genes.
the question is what is the mutation rate?
is it the number of mutated individuals =mutation rate * offspring size
or  the number of mutated individuals =mutation rate * population size
or it is the number of genes in each chromosome of offspring to be swapped (mutation rate * n)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem is scheduling n jobs on n machines and objective function is minimization total completion time Cmax.

Comment: a chromosome is n genes that each gene is a job number. according to the sequence of jobs on the chromosome is the sequence of scheduling jobs on machines.